# Windows Phone back button to terminate the app

Tags: windows-phone-7, back-button

I have a main page with some options. One of them is to navigate to page 1 where there are two arrows. One that navigates to page2, page3, and the other arrow page3, page2, page1 like a loop. There is also an arrow that navigates to main page.

I want to ask if there is a way when the user presses the back button to terminate the app from whatever page the user is currently at and not to navigate through all pages.

edit

if i want when i press the back to always navigate to the mainpage what i have to do ?

Answer (score 3):

clear the back stack inside the `onbackkeypress` function where you want to exit the app. And it will exit the app normally.

**[Updated]**

1) after clearing back stack. Use `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));` to traverse to mainpage and do `e.Cancel = true` in the next statement.

2) Or clear the back stack upto the mainpage. and automatically the back press will take you to the mainpage. inside the mainpage clear the back stack fully inside the `OnNavigatedTo` function so that the first item is always your mainpage and user can exit easily.

```
    protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
     }
```

Comment: clear back stack : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567966/remove-back-entry-in-windows-phone-mango

Comment: thx if i want to navigate always to the mainpage what i have to change

Comment: i have done this but it doesn't work  `protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)  
        {
            while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)  
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();  
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));   
        }`

Comment: you also have to do `e.Cancel = true; return;` to cancel the current back command, try the code which I added. I hope it works. Didnt test it though!

Comment: i tried the code below but it doesnt nothing the back button  `protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
 
       {
 
               while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
 
                   NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
 
               e.Cancel = true;
 
               return;
 
               this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
 
       }
`

Answer (score 2):

```
  protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
```

Comment: thx if i want to navigate always to the mainpage what i have to change ?

Comment: looked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873086/how-to-handle-the-back-button-on-windows-phone-7)

Answer (score 1):

Throw an exception in OnBackKeyPress which terminates the app.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    throw an exception();
}
```

Comment: haha creative, but eh, this not going to pass the market tests

Comment: I am not sure about present days. But my App successfully passed the certification with piece this code in windows phone 7.1 App.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work. If its XNA

```
      if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
```

Comment: using XNA dll in silverlight will not pass certification.
4.2.5) The application must not call any APIs in the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game assembly or the Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics assembly when using any methods from the System.Windows.Controls namespace.
link:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184844(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this,

check

```
e.NavigationMode == System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back
```

in `OnNavigatedTo` event (you need to override this every page) and call

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

there is no direct way of exiting an app.. see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/01/exiting-a-windows-phone-application.aspx)